# Will mysql extension remain or will it be replaced by mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I have a old php script (very long,over a year worth of coding) running on a old pc on the lan with a old xxamp setup. The php script is so old that it contains the `<?php` formatting! This PC will now be replaced but the php script still needs to work. I will switch pc, update xampp to the latest version and migrate everything. I am aware that I'll have to update the old php coding but I am wondering if the whole mysql part MUST be ported to mysqli or if mysql will still exist for the next lets say 10 years. I couldnt find any information on the web.

Thanks

Comment: Its already been replaced by `mysqli_` and the documentation already explicitely says `mysql_` will be removed in a future release.

Comment: If you read the big red warning on *any* of the mysql pages in the manual: `Warning: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.`. If you don't upgrade php, it won't be an issue of mysql disappearing.

Comment: I think `mysqli_` is only an intermediate step to please people who didn't want to jump to PDO instantly. So I'd suggest you just move along to PDO right now, since `mysqli_` will probably end up being deprecated eventually too.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and on the [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) page on php.net.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

It's deprecated and **will** be removed from php in the future. There is no set date, but I can guarantee you that the use of this should stop as soon as possible. Save yourself some heartache and get cracking into `PDO` or `MySQLi`. It'll do your script the world of good!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is already deprecated. You can either use mysqli or PDO in order to handle PHP with MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm already using PHP 5.6 on a local server, and had to rewrite parts of the class I use to connect to the DB: on 5.6, mysql extension has already been removed.

I suggest you to use PDO instead of mysqli (it's a bit more powerful, but of course, it's a personal opinion).